# Why return more rows than the expected after a join?

Tags: sql, impala

I have 2 tables:

```
table 1 : count(*) ->7k rows

table 2 : count(*) ->19k rows
```

when I do this:

```
select count(*)
from table1
inner join table2;
```

It returns 1366127997 rows. How is this possible?

Comment: 7k * 19k = ????

Comment: @jarlh so its a multiplication ? I thought that inner joins only fetches the commons between the tables.

Comment: @Thkas You are doing a _cross_ join.  You need to include an `ON` clause which tells Impala how to match one record to another.  Right now, Impala is matching _every_ record from each table with the other table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks so much for your quick response and your well understood answer.

Comment: Note that on some databases you can't do an inner join without an `ON` clause.  Impala apparently tolerates it, but you get behavior which maybe you didn't expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current query is actually doing a *cross* join:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2;  -- behaves like CROSS JOIN sans an explicit ON clause
```

You most likely were expecting the result from an inner join involving an `ON` clause with a primary and secondary key, something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.fk = t1.pk;
```

This would likely return fewer records than the count you are currently seeing with the cross join.